# Google Map Overlays do not show when I dynamically load the map by create a <script> element in a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, overlay

By reference to Goomap map overlays DEMO https://google-developers.gonglchuangl.net/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-hideshow，I modify from this to dynamically load the map by create a  element in a HTML File. However, I can see that  Map Tiles shows correctly, but missing the overlays.
Besides, when I click the button, a TypeError occurs: `overlay.toggle is not a function`: [TypeErrorPic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaAi9.jpg)

How can I dynamic load a  Element in a HTML file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Showing/Hiding Overlays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"></script> -->

    <script>
        var myscript = document.createElement("script");
        myscript.type = "text/javascript";
        myscript.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=init_callback";
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myscript);
    </script>

    <script>
      // This example adds hide() and show() methods to a custom overlay's prototype.
      // These methods toggle the visibility of the container <div>.
      // Additionally, we add a toggleDOM() method, which attaches or detaches the
      // overlay to or from the map.
      var overlay;

      function init_callback()
      {
        USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
        initMap();
      }


      function initMap() {
          //alert("initMap");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 62.323907, lng: -150.109291},
          mapTypeId: 'satellite'
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
            new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

        // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
        var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
        srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

        overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
      }

      /** @constructor */
      function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

        // Now initialize all properties.
        this.bounds_ = bounds;
        this.image_ = image;
        this.map_ = map;

        // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
        // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
        // method so we'll leave it null for now.
        this.div_ = null;

        // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
        this.setMap(map);
      }

      /**
       * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
       * added to the map.
       */
      USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.style.border = 'none';
        div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
        div.style.position = 'absolute';

        // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = this.image_;
        img.style.width = '100%';
        img.style.height = '100%';
        div.appendChild(img);

        this.div_ = div;

        // Add the element to the "overlayImage" pane.
        var panes = this.getPanes();
        panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);
      };

      USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

        // We use the south-west and north-east
        // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
        // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
        var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

        // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
        // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
        // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
        var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
        var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

        // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
        var div = this.div_;
        div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
        div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
        div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
        div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
      };

      USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
      };

      // Set the visibility to 'hidden' or 'visible'.
      USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
        if (this.div_) {
          // The visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes.
          this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      };

      USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
        if (this.div_) {
          this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      };

      USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
        if (this.div_) {
          if (this.div_.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
            this.show();
          } else {
            this.hide();
          }
        }
      };

      // Detach the map from the DOM via toggleDOM().
      // Note that if we later reattach the map, it will be visible again,
      // because the containing <div> is recreated in the overlay's onAdd() method.
      USGSOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function() {
        if (this.getMap()) {
          // Note: setMap(null) calls OverlayView.onRemove()
          this.setMap(null);
        } else {
          this.setMap(this.map_);
        }
      };

      //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<!-- Add an input button to initiate the toggle method on the overlay. -->
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input type="button" value="Toggle visibility" onclick="overlay.toggle();"></input>
      <input type="button" value="Toggle DOM attachment" onclick="overlay.toggleDOM();"></input>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an ordering issue.  You need to define the entire `USGSOverlay` class inside the `init_callback` function (that runs once the API is loaded).  The way the code in your question runs, the `init_callback` function runs after the rest of the `USGSOverlay` class is defined and overwrites it.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wbuy23xz/1/)

[image: screenshot of working map]

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var myscript = document.createElement("script");
  myscript.type = "text/javascript";
  myscript.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=init_callback";
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(myscript);
</script>

<script>
  // This example adds hide() and show() methods to a custom overlay's prototype.
  // These methods toggle the visibility of the container <div>.
  // Additionally, we add a toggleDOM() method, which attaches or detaches the
  // overlay to or from the map.
  var overlay;
  /** @constructor */
  function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

    // Now initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    this.setMap(map);
  }


  function init_callback() {
    USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
    /**
     * onAdd is called when the map's panes are ready and the overlay has been
     * added to the map.
     */
    USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.border = 'none';
      div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
      div.style.position = 'absolute';

      // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = this.image_;
      img.style.width = '100%';
      img.style.height = '100%';
      div.appendChild(img);

      this.div_ = div;

      // Add the element to the "overlayImage" pane.
      var panes = this.getPanes();
      panes.overlayImage.appendChild(this.div_);
    };

    USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

      // We use the south-west and north-east
      // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
      // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
      var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

      // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
      // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
      // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
      var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
      var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

      // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
      var div = this.div_;
      div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
      div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
      div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
      div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
    };

    USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
      this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    };

    // Set the visibility to 'hidden' or 'visible'.
    USGSOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        // The visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes.
        this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    };

    USGSOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    };

    USGSOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
      if (this.div_) {
        if (this.div_.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
          this.show();
        } else {
          this.hide();
        }
      }
    };

    // Detach the map from the DOM via toggleDOM().
    // Note that if we later reattach the map, it will be visible again,
    // because the containing <div> is recreated in the overlay's onAdd() method.
    USGSOverlay.prototype.toggleDOM = function() {
      if (this.getMap()) {
        // Note: setMap(null) calls OverlayView.onRemove()
        this.setMap(null);
      } else {
        this.setMap(this.map_);
      }
    };
    initMap();
  }


  function initMap() {
    //alert("initMap");
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: {
        lat: 62.323907,
        lng: -150.109291
      },
      mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
      new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

    // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
    var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
    srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
  }


  //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
<!-- Add an input button to initiate the toggle method on the overlay. -->
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="button" value="Toggle visibility" onclick="overlay.toggle();" />
  <input type="button" value="Toggle DOM attachment" onclick="overlay.toggleDOM();" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

can you uncomment this line in your code and try again?

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```